# Determining the measure of a central angle in a circle ( subject math GRE exam 9768 Q.23).

Tags: geometry, gre-exam

The question is given in the following picture:

[image]

I know that the triangle ABC will be an isosceles triangle but I do not know how to use this knowledge in the solution, could anyone help me please ?

Comment: What shape are the triangles $OAB$ and $OAC$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  equilateral triangles. yeah I got it.

Comment: So the quadrilateral $OBAC$ is two equilateral triangles stuck together.

Comment: Could you please name your questions so they refer to _the topic they are about_ instead of impenetrable reference codes for where in some unspecified filing system you found the problem that prompted you to ask? Thank you.

Comment: ok I will do @HenningMakholm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Let the radius of the two circles to be $r$, then
$OA=OB=OC=r=AO=AB=AC$